# Parallel read_table in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a way to parallelize an invocation of read_table()? In my case it's CPU bound due to date parsing. I don't see any way to achieve that from reading the docs. The only thing that comes to mind is splitting the input file, calling read_table in parallel and then concatenating the dataframes.

Comment: no; fyi its faster to do date parsing after (via ``pd.to_datetime``) if you are passing a format. splitting and concatenating are a valid solution in any event.

Comment: would calling pd.to_datetime from apply allow for easier parralelization after import or would you still have to manually split up the data frame into N/M parts (N = num rows, M = num logical procs) and execute afterward?  I'm really hoping for some of the straightforward parallelization cases pandas gets n_jobs type support that some scikit-learn functions have (like gridsearch).

Comment: Yes, I would love to see sklearn style parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

This will read CSV files in parallel and concatenate them. The annoying bit is that it won't handle `numpy` types, so it can't parse dates. I have been struggling with the same problem, but so far it seems that libraries such as `execnet` can't handle types that are not built-in. That's why I turn DataFrames into `json` before sending. It strips the types to basic Python ones.

**Edit:** If you need to parse dates, maybe a more sensible approach would be to remotely read the `CSV` files, parse the dates and save them as `pickle` to the hard drive. Then you could read the pickle files in the main process and concatenate them. I haven't tried that to see if it would lead to a gain in performance.

**remote_read_csv.py**

```
import cPickle as pickle

if __name__ == '__channelexec__':
    reader = pickle.loads(channel.receive())

    for filename in channel:
        channel.send(reader(filename).to_json())
```

This below makes use of the module above. I tested it in IPython.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat, read_csv, read_json
from numpy import random
import execnet
import remote_read_csv
import cPickle as pickle
import itertools
import psutil

### Create dummy data and save to CSV

def rdf():
    return DataFrame((random.rand(4, 3) * 100).astype(int))

d1 = rdf()
d2 = rdf()
d3 = rdf()

dfsl = [d1, d2, d3]
names = 'd1.csv d2.csv d3.csv'.split()
for i in range(3):
    dfsl[i].to_csv(names[i])

### Read CSV files in separate threads then concatenate

reader = pickle.dumps(read_csv)

def set_gateways(remote_module, *channel_sends):
    gateways = []
    channels = []
    for i in range(psutil.NUM_CPUS):
        gateways.append(execnet.makegateway())
        channels.append(gateways[i].remote_exec(remote_module))
        for send in channel_sends:
            channels[i].send(send)
    return (gateways, channels)

def para_read(names):
    gateways, channels = set_gateways(remote_read_csv, reader)
    mch = execnet.MultiChannel(channels)
    queue = mch.make_receive_queue()
    channel_ring = itertools.cycle(mch)
    for f in names:
        channel = channel_ring.next()
        channel.send(f)
    dfs = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        channel, df = queue.get()
        dfs.append(df)

    [gw.exit() for gw in gateways]
    return concat([read_json(i) for i in dfs], keys=names)

para_read(names)
```